# python - not creating image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to import an image, then manipulate its rgb colors.
This is what i've got:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('grapes.jpg')
pixels = list(image.getdata())

for pixel in pixels:
    pixel = (pixel[0] - 50, pixel[1] , pixel[2])

image.putdata(pixel)
image.save('grapes_modified.jpg')
```

as you can see, i am trying to reduce the red channel. This doesn't work. It produces the exact duplicate of the imported image.
even if i where to do something like this:  `pixel = (0,0,0)`. It would produce a duplicate image.

so how do i modify the image?

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The for cycle doesn't replace the content of each pixel, it just creates a new instance and then tosses it away. You should create a new array, for example:

```
newdata = [ (pixel[0] - 50, pixel[1] , pixel[2]) for pixel in pixels ]
```